# postgreSQL backup restoration using bkp.tar.gz file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am an Oracle DBA and I got a `bkp.tar.tgz` PostgreSQL backup file to restore on server. Vendor provided backup file before closing contract. I don't have any information for backup file.

I have below questions.

1. PostgreSQL backup can be restored on cross platform OS? If no, then how can I know what is source OS.
2. PostgreSQL db version needs to be same? Or doesn't matter? How to find db version from bkp file? They said it's PostgreSQL 9.4.5
3. Is there any other way I can access data from backup file?

Comment: Can you run `tar -tz bkp.tar.tgz` and add the result (or part of it if it is a lot) to the question? It is probably either an archive of a physical backup (then it would be interesting if it contains a file `backup_label`) or a logical backup ("export" in Oracle jargon), then it would be good to know in which format. Regardless of which it is, you will need PostgreSQL 9.4 to restore it (use 9.4.latest). To save yourself the detective work, can you ask the people that produced it?

Comment: I have unzip file in windows and linux were, able to see below files /db/db.backup and tree files. Does postgreSQL backup works on crossplatform ?

Comment: It depends. Logical backups are platform agnostic, physical ones not. What is a "tree file"? I'd need more information than that (like the file names). It's a good idea to add relevant information to the question itself rather than as a comment.